# border and background of html tag

Tags: html, css

```
html { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#006600; border-style:solid;  } /*Dark Green*/
body { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#660000; border-style:dotted; } /*Dark Brown*/

<html>
    <body>
      test
    </body> 
</html>
```

Why does the background-color of html tag extend the full window but the border-style of the tag remain confined just outside the body box border.

Comment: If you are asking a theoretical question, I don't know.  Practically, though, you can accomplish what you're asking by adding a width/height attribute to the html style (e.g. 100%) to get the border to be around the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the right amount of height and width should solve your problem.
Try it with appropriate values of height and width.

---

See this link : [Understanding the HTML versus BODY Element in CSS](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html)

> The html and body elements are
> distinct block-level entities, in a
> parent/child relationship.
> The html
> element's height and width are
> controlled by the browser window.
>
> The body element is (by default)
> position:static, which means that
> positioned children of it are
> positioned relative to the html
> element's coordinate system.
>
> In
> almost all modern browsers, the
> built-in offset from the edge of the
> page is applied through a margin on
> the body element, not padding on the
> html element.

Hope you get some idea to your doubt.